Calling a function while trying to input in a file in python
so as you can see in the image i was trying to call the main() function which calls the tables function which prints the table of a given number till times 10. But when i try tables.write it looks like i can not call a function over there. is any way by which i can input the table in the file (tables.txt)?the reference code
i am a new learner and i was expecting for it to work smoothly as i had tried to explain in the details of the problem.

The with open... statement, together with the write logic, should also reside in your tables function. Also, edit your question and provide the code as a formatted text, not as an image, so we could copy and paste it ourselves.

Please don't post images of code - post it here, properly formatted as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Please add properly formatted code to your question (not a hyperlink to an image of it) then explain what you hope the code will achieve for any given input.

The with open... statement, together with the write logic, should also reside in your tables function.
I understood that you want to write the main input inside the table, and I assumed that you would like to write what you printed in the tables function.
def tables(n):
    i = 1

    # Open the file, and specify that it is for writing purposes
    with open("tables.txt", "w") as table:
        while i <= 10:
            print(n*i)
            i += 1
            # Convert the number to a string and write it to the file
            table.write(str(i))

def main():
    n = int(input("enter a number: "))
    tables(n)

main()  


I'm surprised that this "answer" has been accepted because it clearly cannot work. The file is not writable and even if it was, the call to write() would fail with a TypeError

@SIGHUP additional modification has been made to the code, in order to make it work

@SIGHUP that was my first time using stackoverflow, You could say that i was just looking around with the features and in order to appreciate mario trying to answer my question i gave him the check mark. Now i realize the meaning of the accept this answer mark.
